# Anchor ul-li blinks/flicker after click on a link problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I decided to do a `li` hover effect.
Cursor hovers on `anchor li`, `li` moves down to simulate a click effect.

Every time after `li` click I see one blink of `anchor li` background.

I googled Flash of original Content (or FOOC) add similar issues
but can't find the right answer :(

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Reset styles */
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,
del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,
dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,form,label,legend,caption,tfoot,thead 
{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;background:transparent;}

body {line-height:1;}
ol,ul {list-style:none;}
blockquote, q {quotes:none;}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {content: none;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;} 
html, body {height: 100%;}
h1 {font-size:1.35em;} h2 {font-size:1.25em;} h3 {font-size: 1.15em;} h4 {font-size: 1.1em;} h5 {font-size: 1em;}
a img  {border:0 none;}
a {text-decoration:none}
div, header, aside, section {box-sizing: border-box;}
.clr {clear:both;height:1px;font:1px/1px sans-serif;}

body{background-color:#5c8d9f; }

#container {
 margin:0 auto; overflow: hidden; display: flex;
 width:100%; height: 100%; max-width:1366px; border-left: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
 background:#3b3f42 ;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

#sidebar {
 width: 180px;height: 100%; border-right: 0px solid #1c1e20;
 font-size: 15px;text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);}
#sidebar a:link, a:visited {color:#9fa8b0;}
#sidebar a:hover {color:#fff !important;  }
#sidebar a:focus {color:#6e7a84 !important;}
#sidebar ul li {border-top: 1px solid #4c5052;border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1e20; }
#sidebar ul span {padding-right: 5px; }
#sidebar ul a { 
 display: block;width: 180px;box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 7px 2px 7px 10px;vertical-align: middle; text-decoration: none;}

#sidebar ul li a:active {padding: 8px 2px 6px 10px;box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #27496d,inset 0 5px 20px #193047;}
#sidebar ul li.active a {background: red; color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);}
#sidebar ul li.active {border-top: 1px solid #282a2d;}
#sidebar ul li.active span {color: #e1533d;} 
#sidebar ul li.active:hover span {color: #fff;}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {background: #125072;background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0186ba,  #125072);}

#sidebar ul li.active a:focus span {color:#6e7a84;}
#logo {
 margin: 0 auto; box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 200px; height: 45px; border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1e20;
 
}

/*--- Content ---*/

#content {width:100%;height:100%; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 45px; padding-bottom: 1px;}
/*--- Header ---*/

header {
 display: flex;margin-top: -45px;border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1e20;height:45px; border-left: 1px solid #1c1e20;
 color:#fff;font-family: SourceSansb, sans-serif; 
}

/*--- Header menu ---*/ 
#menu ul {margin: 0; overflow: hidden;padding:0;text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);}
#menu ul li {float: left;box-sizing: border-box;}
#menu ul li a {
   float: left;height: 44px;box-sizing: border-box;
    color:#d6d6d6;line-height:24px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background:#3C4042;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    border-left: 1px solid #4c5052;
    border-right: 1px solid #1c1e20;
  
}
#menu ul li.active a {
    background: #282a2d;
 box-shadow: inset 0 5px 20px #282a2d;
 color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);
}
#menu li ul {
    background:#3C4042;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    left: -999em;
    margin: 35px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#menu li ul a {
    background: none;
    border: 0 none;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 120px;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
#menu ul li a:hover, #menu ul li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #125072;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0186ba,  #125072);
}
#menu ul li a:active  {padding: 11px 20px 9px;box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #27496d,inset 0 5px 20px #193047; color: #6e7a84;
}


section {
 overflow-y: scrolls;overflow-x: hidden;box-sizing: border-box;
 width:100%; height:100% !important;color:#3c4148; margin: 2px; padding:15px 2px 10px 2px; 
 border:0px solid #d1d1d1;
 text-align:center;background-color: #eeeeee; font-family: arial, helvetica sanserif;
}

.under {
 display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;
 height:100%;
}



#test1  {margin-top: 10px; text-align: left;font-family: ; 
}
#test2  {margin-top: 10px; text-align: left;font-family: ; 
}
#test3  {margin-top: 10px; text-align: left;font-family: ; 
}
#test4  {margin-top: 10px; text-align: left;font-family: ; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"  />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<link href="css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
 
 act='test';
 if ( act == "") $('#index').addClass('active');
 else  $('#test').addClass('active');

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<aside id="sidebar">
<div id="logo"><br/></div>
 <ul class="nav">
  <li id="index" class=""><a href="index.php"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-home"></span>
   Home</a></li>
  <li id="status" class=""><a href="?status"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-table"></span>
   Status</a></li>
  <li id="test" class=""><a href="?test"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-text-resize"></span>
   Test</a></li>

 </ul>
 
</aside><!--end sidebar -->
    


<div id="content"> 
<header>
    
 <nav id="menu">
  <ul>
   <li id="pubs" class=""><a href="?pubs" >PUBS</a></li>
   <li id="personal" class=""><a href="?personal">PERSONAL</a>
   </li>
  
  </ul>
 </nav><!--end menu_line -->
</header><!--end header -->


<section>

<br />
Test


<hr/>

<br />

<div id="test1" >
1  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br/>
 
</div>

</section><!--end data-->
</div><!--end content-->
</div><!--end container-->
</body>
</html>
```

I uploaded a snippet [here](http://www.test.kbk-legend.hr/index.php).

Can anyone advise on how I can stop this from happening?

Thanks for any help or suggestions you may have!

Comment: The link doesn't link to any code snippet. You would need to include your code and the default mechanism for that is to do it directly on Stack Overflow in the question post (unless there's an appealing case to warrant an exception).

Comment: It seems the flicker issue is solved by you. right ?

Comment: No, the problem still exist.
Now I changed background color of active class to red.
After I click anchor li I first see blink/flash of red background
and then hover background (blue) because the cursor is still hovers li.

Comment: Hi @DVC,   the issue here is the active class being applied on document ready. So there is a lag. I'm not fully sure because I couldn't test but you could try to extend the #sidebar ul li a:hover  with  #sidebar ul li.active a:hover     . So it will be like    #sidebar ul li a:hover, #sidebar ul li.active a:hover {  background: #125072; }

Comment: Dear arvie, thanks for the suggestion, but it does not work.
You are right, active class is applied with jQuery after a document is ready.
But even If I delete javaScript and change background to, for instance yellow,
I still after click see short blink/flash of yellow background and then hover background (blue)!
So even without the active class I can see short flash.
The problem is more visible in Firefox because in Chrome 
hover gets dismissed after the click, although the pointer hovers li element.